# Property Request.Headers.Date in System.Web.Http

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

Hi I am trying to find the property Date of the Header in the System.Web.HttpRequest but I cannot find it. This property is in the System.Net lib but not in the System.Web

Any idea where or how to find it?

My request is:

```
Authorization: blablabla
Date: Wed, 25 Feb 2015 21:36:39 +0000
Host: localhost:57449
Content-Length: 128
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are two completely different types with very different purposes (`System.Web.HttpRequest` is for servers; `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` is for clients). Differences in the design reflect those different uses.

Have you tried looking in `HttpRequest`'s [`Headers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.headers%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collection?